# Instant App - Multi-Module Project - Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

My project has multi-modules to support instant apps. After updating Android Studio and Gradle, started getting below warning.

```
Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

Gradle dependencies for `ModuleA`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':base')
    compile project(path: ':ModuleB')
    compile project(path: ':ModuleC')

    ...
}
```

Gradle dependencies for `ModuleB`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':base')
    compile project(path: ':ModuleC')

    ...
}
```

As mentioned [here](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html), I've tried to update `compile` to `implementation` and/or `api`. But in either case, build fails or app crashes, with message like cant find `ClassB` or `ModuleB`.

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue for multi-module project?

Comment: Can you mention the exact error that you get after replacing compile with `api` or `implementation`? As you might know, you should import a `module3` as an api in `module2` if you want `module2` to expose the classes in `module3` to whichever module `module2` is a dependency of.

Comment: Please can you check multi-feature-module sample project might it help you https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/multi-feature-module

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you on?

Comment: Are ModuleB/C feature modules or library modules? Feature modules should be `feature project()` Library modules can be either `api` or `implementation`, depending how you want to expose the modules further down the tree.